# How to Display a List of Parent Categories (with Links) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So i have this dilemma on **displaying a list of all the parent categories** in wordpress.

I'm using this code below:

```
<ul><li><?php wp_list_categories('orderby=order&title_li=&depth=1'); ?></li></ul>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work which I really don't know why. what happens is it only shows the only ONE category.

I would appreciate anyone's help on this please.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you looking for a way to show all top-level categories? Or all categories that have children? Or the parent category of a specific category/post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one. I have tested before

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'hide_empty' => 0,
      'parent' => 0,
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach($categories as $category) {

      echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br>';

      } 
  ?>
```

**Or try this. Let me know which one is better.**

```
<?php wp_list_cats('optionall=0&depth=1&list=0&exclude=1&children=0&hide_empty=0'); ?`>
```